# Large MySQL table that need to index some fields?

Tags: mysql

I would like to know some hints about how to index some columns of a MySQL table that has about 28 million rows.

Maybe I could recreate the table indexing it properly, then import these rows?

Could someone help me with this please.

Comment: You don't need to recreate table. Just use `CREATE INDEX` and it will index it.

Comment: i know but are 28 millions of rows

Comment: it will take so long time, isn't?

Comment: It will take just as long if you recreate the table.

Comment: I guess you're saying that you'll create a new table and copy the data from the old table, so you don't interfere with the old table, and then rename them.

Comment: well not, my problem is the 28 millions of rows ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 28 million rows is a medium sized table; MySQL handles 10**9 rows or more with ease with the proper indexes. But we can't help you without knowing more about your table, and how you need to access it.

Comment: Is the table using InnoDB or MyISAM ???

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to create a single index, CREATE INDEX would be the way to go.

However, if you wish to setup your table with multiple indices, setting up a new empty table and then copying from your old to your new table is IMO a more practical solution, since you can get everything ready and then simply run the insert when it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create an index is to use `CREATE INDEX` statement. There are only 2 ways to apply this statement:
1. Empty table and copy data into it
2. To use it on populated table.

In Case 2 you need to consider availabe DB space, temp space, log space as well as memory and CPU time. If this table is large for your hardware, then there is a high chance that you'll run out of space before create index operation completes.

However, I would suggest to look at the way you are managing this table and apply techniques like partitioning or `MERGEd` tables. it looks like the better option for you will be to move data into a new table. This gives you an opportunity to do more to make your data more manageble.